# Where are dialer's "All Contacts" coming from?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app, motorola-moto-g

Stock Moto G running 4.4.2, initially set up using Motorola Migrate to transfer my data from an HTC Desire S.

I have Google, Skype, Facebook and LinkedIn accounts on my phone, and all the correct contact details from all those accounts are shown in the People app. Happy days.

The fun starts when I open the dialer, and select "All Contacts". Here I see all sorts of ancient contacts who did once exist on my previous phone(s), some of whom I may have called at some point but most of whom I never have. They don't exist in the People app, or in the Call History, or on my SIM card—indeed, if I tap one of them to look at their details, there's an "Add to My Contacts" button there.

Some of them are contacts that I used to have on my phone 1 or 2 phones ago and long since deleted, others appear to be old details for contacts that I have since updated or renamed.

Where have these ghosts come from, and how can I banish them?

Comment: Within settings of your phone there will be an option called `accounts & sync` you can sync or unsync the contacts of the app you need

Comment: That wasn't the problem, everything was syncing correctly. I've just figured it out though, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: It appears these contacts were in the "Other contacts" on gmail.com. I'm not entirely sure how they got there or why there is no such group in the People app where I can see or edit them, but at least I can delete them now!

Comment: Seems that Gmail keeps a record of everybody you've ever talked to via email. My "other contacts" is full of crap as well...